# Sending the details of the multi form to the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have to create a form which includes Batches and Samples.

General idea would be Batches having (`received:date`, `group_leader:string`, `contact_person:string`, `batch_comment:string` and `num_of_samples:integer`) .
N.B batches have many samples.
now the Samples include ( `sample_name`, `species`, `sample_type`, `ini_conc`, `ini_vol`, and `sample_comment`).

Now as these are of one to many relationships, I have created a form after following many tutorials having a page showing batch detail entry as well as asking for how many samples it involved in each batch. After the user types in (for eg. 3), the form generates three fields having sample details (also including `name`, `species`, `type`, `conc`, `vol`, etc.) but I was not able to send these details to the database.
The only thing that updates the database is one sample information.
my view looks something like this :

New sample:

```
  <p><% form_for(sample) do |f| %></p>
    <p><% (1..@batch.sample_no).each do |i| -%></p>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <p>
    <%= f.hidden_field :batch_id %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :sample_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :sname %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :organism %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :organism, :rows => 2 %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :sample_type %><br />
    <%= f.select(:samp_type, %w{ DNA RNA}) %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :ini_conc %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :ini_conc %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :ini_vol %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :ini_vol %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :storage_space %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :storage_space %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :samp_comment %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :samp_comment, :rows => 3 %>
  </p>
    <% end -%>
  <p><%= f.submit 'Submit' %></p>
<% end %>
```

I haven't done anything much with my controller. (in fact I have no idea which controller I should add codes to) meaning I have created two scaffolds, one for batch and one for samples and I have made a partial of the samples_view_new.html.erb and saved it in the batch_view folder which gives me an opportunity to add samples in the `show_html.erb` of the batch.

my models of `batch.rb` and `sample.rb` look some thing like this

```
<p>class Batch < ActiveRecord::Base</p>
  <p>has_many :samples</p>
<p>end</p>

<p>class Sample < ActiveRecord::Base </p>
 <p>belongs_to :batch</p>
<p>end</p>
```

Comment: first off, check your formatting of this question - we can't see the ruby markup. start the code on a new line and indent all lines by 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have the solution to the problem...

My main idea was to send multiple rows in the database at once... so just follow this tutorial

http://www.stephenchu.com/2008/03/paramsfu-3-using-fieldsfor-and-index.html

Answer (score 1):

if I understand your requirements correctly, you're searching for nested forms as excellently described by Ryan Bates at railscasts.com

Tutorial 1: [Nested Model Form Part 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)

Tutorial 2: [Nested Model Form Part 2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2)

Here is some more help for you:

In your Bash model

```
has_many :samples
accepts_nested_attributes_for :samples
```

Your Bash Controller will have at least 2 actions: new and create
In your new action:

```
@bash = Bash.build
4.times { @bash.samples.build } # where 4 is the no. of samples, could also be param[:amount] in case you add a preliminary action with a form and an amount field, but I suggest using javascript as described in Tutorial 2 above for better user experience
```

In the create action:

```
@bash = Bash.new(params[:bash]) # you now have access to @bash.samples
if @bash.save ...
```

And finally the "new" view:

```
<%= form_for @bash do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :group_leader %> <!-- ... -->
  <%= f.fields_for :samples do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.text_field :sample_name  %> <!-- ... -->
  <% end %>
<%= end %>
```

With this and the tutorials you should now be able to build a killer app for your degree's application. Good luck!

Comment: Hi blackbird 07, Thanks for the prompt reply. I have checked with the railscasts episodes but I am not sure i require that way. Ill tell you y. the reason is because, I need a page that asks the user how many samples it needs as input. Then, it generates the sample fields directly giving an option to fill in details. but unfortunately, I am unable to fill those details in the database because I have not touched anything in the batch_controller as well as sample controller. so this makes my situation more complicated. I hope you understand my problem

Comment: Sorry, do not see the difference. The important thing is [1] the setup of your models (associations) and accepts_nested_attributes_for
[2] logic in the controller action. For your scenario, you could have an intermediate action that renders the form for entering the number of samples, then in the controller processing this form, render the final form with params[:amount].times { batch.sample.build }

Comment: Sorry I don't have much time right now, but later I will update my answer to give you some more hints

Comment: Thanks a lot blackbird. thing is that I am new to rails and ruby... so I am not able to understand properly.. I am new to programming and desperate for getting a nice application for my degree

Comment: Answer is now edited. Hope it helps you on the way. Rails will take care of saving the samples to the db.

Comment: Blackbird.. Thank you so much for the time and advice.. Really appreciate your dedication towards the field...